# Add new property to JSON file key using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Sorry, I'm still new to programming, so please pardon me, I need help adding a new property inside a JSON file. :(

I want it to **edit** the JSON file~! meow~

**animals.json:** (Before Adding New Property)

```
{
  "cat": {
    "name": "Hiro",
    "age": 6
  },
  "wolf": {
    "name": "Kairo",
    "age": 3
  }
}
```

**index.js** (Example Code to add new Property)

```
var file = require('../../data/animals.json');

file["wolf"].push({gender: "female"})
```

**the new animals.json after running index.js**

```
{
  "cat": {
    "name": "Hiro",
    "age": 6
  },
  "wolf": {
    "name": "Kairo",
    "age": 3,
    "gender": "female"
  }
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
var file = require('../../data/animals.json');
const fs = require("fs");

file.wolf.gender = "female";

fs.writeFileSync("../../data/animals.json", JSON.stringify(file));
```

Using dot notation, you can either create or update property on a non null property.

Comment: can you update your question to add this requirement? you need to use `fs` to overwrite the json file. let me see if I can update my answer.